# Best way to store chart image/data?

Tags: android, charts, drawing

I am developing a dictionary app for stock chart patterns. I know I have the following options:

**1. Simply store all the images for each pattern in the assets/ (or res/) folder.** This method will increase the app size enormously because the images with different resolutions for the same pattern should be stored altogether. However, it's straightforward and easy to implement.

**2. Store the pattern data in SQLite (or any other storage), render the chart using the data when needed.** This method makes more sense than 1., but it take some effort to make the drawing function.

Which one is the best way to store the chart image/data? Or is there any other way I did not figure out? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add SVG library and store charts as vector graphics. But your option 2 is the best if you want 5-star app. Just use some charting library and store charts in some simple format like json. You're not going to update those charts all the time so storing it in sql is overkill.